# Web Scraping with rvest and R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to web scrape the total assets of a particular fund in this case ADAFX from http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/adafx/quote.html. But the result is always charecter (empty); what am I doing wrong?

I have used rvest before with mixed results, so I figured time to get expert help from the community of trusted gurus (thats you).

```
library(rvest)      
Symbol.i ="ADAFX"
url <-Paste("http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/",Symbol.i,"/quote.html",sep="")
  tryCatch(NetAssets.i <- url %>%
             read_html() %>%
             html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="gr_total_asset_wrap"]/span/span') %>%
             html_text(), error = function(e) NetAssets.i = NA)
```

Thank you in advance, 
Cheers,

Aaron Soderstrom

Comment: You do know that there's a morningstar api, right? See [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c7d9c19cc67e03641966064d1518ed41) for an example

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the API, but am trying to build a custom  fund screener that the API does not include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dynamic page that loads data for the various sectinons via XHR requests, so you have to look at the Developer Tools Network tab to get the target content URLs.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

res <- GET(url = "http://quotes.morningstar.com/fundq/c-header",
           query = list(
             t="XNAS:ADAFX",
             region="usa",
             culture="en-US",
             version="RET",
             test="QuoteiFrame"
           )
)

content(res) %>%
  html_nodes("span[vkey='TotalAssets']") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  trimws()
## [1] "20.6  mil"
```

Comment: Looks like I have my homework cut out for me, thanks for providing me with a start!

Comment: Followup question, when running the code through a loop it throughs the error:                                                                                                               `Error in UseMethod("content", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "response"`                                                                                                                 Any thought on whats going on. Even your original code will have this error once it happens. I have to restart my R session to fix it.

Comment: wld need to see the loop. prbly a candidate for a follow-up SO q.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://omegasqrd.bitrix24.com/~IgVC1) is the csv file it calls.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tm)
library(plyr)
require("dplyr")

MF.List <- read.csv("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Investment Committee/Screener/Filtered Funds.csv")
Category.list <- read.csv("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Investment Committee/Screener/Category.csv")
Category.list <- na.omit(Category.list)

Category.name <- "Financial"
MF.Category.List <- filter(MF.List, Category == Category.name)

morningstar.scrape <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(MF.Category.List)){

  Symbol.i =as.character(MF.Category.List[i,"Symbol"])
  res <- GET(url = "http://quotes.morningstar.com/fundq/c-header",
             query = list(
               t=paste("XNAS:",Symbol.i,sep=""),
               region="usa",
               culture="en-US",
               version="RET",
               test="QuoteiFrame"
             )
  )

  tryCatch(
    TTM.Yield <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='ttmYield']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) TTM.Yield<-NA)

  tryCatch(
    Load <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='Load']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Load = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Total.Assets <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='TotalAssets']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Total.Assets = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Expense.Ratio <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='ExpenseRatio']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Expense.Ratio = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Fee.Level <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='FeeLevel']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Fee.Level = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Turnover <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='Turnover']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Turnover = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Status <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='Status']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Status = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Min.Investment <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='MinInvestment']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Min.Investment = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Yield.30day <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='Yield']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Yield.30day = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Investment.Style <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='InvestmentStyle']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Investment.Style = NA)

  tryCatch(
    Bond.Style <- content(res) %>%
      html_nodes("span[vkey='BondStyle']") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      trimws()
    , error = function(e) Bond.Style = NA)

  x.frame <- c(Symbol =as.character(Symbol.i),TTM.Yield = as.character(TTM.Yield), Load = as.character(Load),
               Total.Assets = as.character(Total.Assets),Expense.Ratio = as.character(Expense.Ratio),
               Turnover = as.character(Turnover), Status = as.character(Status), 
               Yield.30day = as.character(Yield.30day), 
               Investment.Style = as.character(Investment.Style),Bond.Style = as.character(Bond.Style))

  morningstar.scrape[[i]] = x.frame
  x.frame = NULL
}

MS.scrape <- do.call(rbind, morningstar.scrape)
```

Comment: It looks like adding in `library(tm)` is causing the issue, I removed the tm package from the code and used gerpl instead of filter. Now the loop works fine. So the issue is that the two packages do not play nice; as to why, I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Working code,

I added a function to the web scrape and removed the library(tm).

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)


    get.morningstar <- function(Symbol.i,htmlnode){
      res <- GET(url = "http://quotes.morningstar.com/fundq/c-header",
                 query = list(
                   t=paste("XNAS:",Symbol.i,sep=""),
                   region="usa",
                   culture="en-US",
                   version="RET",
                   test="QuoteiFrame"
                 )
      )

      x <- content(res) %>%
        html_nodes(htmlnode) %>%
        html_text() %>%
        trimws()

      return(x)
    }



    MF.List <- read.csv("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Bitrix24/Investment Committee/Screener/Filtered Funds.csv")
    Category.list <- read.csv("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/Bitrix24/Investment Committee/Screener/Category.csv")
    Category.list <- na.omit(Category.list)

    Category.name <- "Small Growth"
    MF.Category.List <- MF.List[grepl(Category.name,MF.List$Category), ]
    morningstar.scrape <- list()

    for(i in 1:nrow(MF.Category.List)){
      Symbol.i =as.character(MF.Category.List[i,"Symbol"])
      try(Total.Assets <- get.morningstar(Symbol.i,"span[vkey='TotalAssets']"))
      print(Total.Assets)
    }
```